# Codename One: add a text to an InfiniteProgress()

Tags: codenameone

I have a full screen [`InfiniteProgress`](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/InfiniteProgress.html) in this way:

```
Dialog ip = new InfiniteProgress().showInifiniteBlocking();
```

How can I add a text over that `InfiniteProgress`, such as `Loading Data...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is pretty limited I suggest just taking it and modifying it as:

```
Form f = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
f.setTintColor(0x90000000);
Dialog d = new Dialog("My Title", new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
d.putClientProperty("isInfiniteProgress", true);
d.setDialogUIID("Container");
d.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, this);
d.setTransitionInAnimator(CommonTransitions.createEmpty());
d.setTransitionOutAnimator(CommonTransitions.createEmpty());
d.showPacked(BorderLayout.CENTER, false);
```

This might require customizing the title color styling too.

Comment: Thank you very much. A note for the reader: `d.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, this);` can be replaced with any custom component.